# Undo Redo in richtextbox using undo and redo functions

Tags: c#, richtextbox, undo-redo

I have tried 
if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z))
                RTB.Undo();
and .Redo() but nothing reflected in the richtextbox.
I tried with sendmessage too. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and setting a breakpoint on the Undo().

Comment: @RichardSchneider Yes, I have. I am writing this inside KeyDown event. I also saw that Undo does not work with KeyPress and textChanged events. Is there a need to set the clipboard text everytime? I am really confused here.

Comment: @RichardSchneider may be i am missing to set some property here. No idea...

Comment: `Undo` returns true if something has been undone.  Maybe you check the result.

Comment: @RichardSchneider undo has a void return type...

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the PresentationFramework documentation not Winforms!  I have no more ideas

Answer (score 0):

i tried id and it works correctly.

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
                richTextBox1.Undo();
```

did you enable the KeyPreview Property of current form for start catching key downs?

talking about this property.
[image]

Comment: There is no such property. I can only see an event with similar name.

Comment: talking about form properties.and you dont need to set the clipboard text everytime.rtb doing it already.

Comment: oops... sorry was checking the rtb properties... Thanks will check that